# Include cuda kernel in my project

Tags: c++, g++, cuda, linker-errors

I have this c++ project in which I call a cuda kernel by means of a wrapper function.

My c++ file looks like this (this is **extern.cc**):

```
#include "extern.h"  
#include "qc/operator.h"  
#include "qc/quStates.h"  
#include "gpu.h"  
...  
ROUTINE(ext_bit) {  
    int i;  
    quState *qbit;
    PAR_QUSTATE(q,"q");
    opBit *op;
    tComplex I(0,1);
    tComplex sg= inv ? -1 : 1;
    char c=(def->id())[0];
    if(def->id().length()!=1) c='?';
    switch(c) {
        case 'H': op=new opBit(1,1,1,-1,sqrt(0.5)); break;
        case 'X': op=new opBit(0,1,1,0);        break;
        case 'Y': op=new opBit(0,-I,I,0);       break;
        case 'Z': op=new opBit(1,0,0,-1);       break;
        case 'S': op=new opBit(1,0,0,sg*I);     break;
        case 'T': op=new opBit(1,0,0,sqrt(0.5)+sg*sqrt(0.5)*I); break;
        case '?':
        default: EXTERR("unknown single qubit operator "+def->id());
    } 

    // This is where I call my wrapper function
    // the error that I get is: expected primary-expression before ',' token
    gpucaller(opBit, q);  

    qcl_delete(op);
    return 0;
}
```

where *"gpucaller"* is my wrapper function that calls the kernel, both defined in **cuda_kernel.cu**:

```
/* compiling with:
nvcc -arch sm_11 -c -I"/home/glu/NVIDIA_GPU_Computing_SDK/C/common/inc" -I"." -I"./qc" -I"/usr/local/cuda/include" -o cuda_kernel.o cuda_kernel.cu
*/


#ifndef _CUDA_KERNEL_H_
#define _CUDA_KERNEL_H_


#define MAX_QUBITS 25
#define BLOCKDIM 512
#define MAX_TERMS_PER_BLOCK (2*BLOCKDIM)
#define THREAD_MASK (~0ul << 1)


// includes
#include <cutil_inline.h>

#include "gpu.h"    


__constant__ float devOpBit[2][2];


__global__ void qcl1(cuFloatComplex *a, int N, int qbCount, int blockGrpSize, int k)
{
    //int idx = blockIdx.x * BLOCKDIM + threadIdx.x;
    //int tx = threadIdx.x;

    cuFloatComplex t0_0, t0_1, t1_0, t1_1;
    int x0_idx, x1_idx;
    int i, grpSize, b0_idx, b1_idx;

    __shared__ cuFloatComplex aS[MAX_TERMS_PER_BLOCK];
    ...
}



void gpucaller(opBit* op, quBaseState* q) {
    // make an operator copy
    float** myOpBit = (float**)op->getDeviceReadyOpBit();

    unsigned int timer = 0;
    cuFloatComplex *a_d;
    long int N = 1 << q->mapbits();
    int size = sizeof(cuFloatComplex) * N;

    // start timer
    cutilCheckError( cutCreateTimer( &timer));
    cutilCheckError( cutStartTimer( timer));    
    // allocate device memory
    cudaMalloc((void**)&a_d,size);  
    // copy host memory to device
    cudaMemcpy(a_d, q->termsarray, size, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
    // copy quantic operator to constant memory
    cutilSafeCall( cudaMemcpyToSymbol(devOpBit, myOpBit, 2*sizeof(float[2]), 0) );
    printf("Cuda errors: %s\n", cudaGetErrorString( cudaGetLastError() ) );    

    // setup execution parameters
    dim3 dimBlock(BLOCKDIM, 1, 1);    
    int n_blocks = N/MAX_TERMS_PER_BLOCK + (N%MAX_TERMS_PER_BLOCK == 0 ? 0:1);
    dim3 dimGrid(n_blocks, 1, 1);
    ...        

    // execute the kernel
    qcl1<<< dimGrid, dimBlock >>>(a_d, N, gates, blockGrpSize, k);
    // check if kernel execution generated and error
    cutilCheckMsg("Kernel execution failed");
    ...
    // copy result from device to host
    cudaMemcpy(q->termsarray, a_d, size, cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);   
    // stop timer
    cutilCheckError( cutStopTimer( timer));
    //printf( "GPU Processing time: %f (ms)\n", cutGetTimerValue( timer));    
    cutilCheckError( cutDeleteTimer( timer));
    // cleanup memory on device
    cudaFree(a_d);
    cudaThreadExit();
}


#endif // #ifndef _CUDA_KERNEL_H_
```

and "**gpu.h**" has the following content:

```
#ifndef _GPU_H_
#define _GPU_H_

#include "qc/operator.h"
#include "qc/qustates.h"

void gpucaller(opBit* op, quBaseState* q);

#endif // #ifndef _GPU_H_
```

I don't include the .cu file in my c++ file, I only include the .h file (gpu.h - contains the prototype of my kernel caller function) in both the c++ and the .cu files.

> I compile the .cu file with nvcc, and link the resulting .o file in my project's Makefile.
>   Also, I didn't forget to add the "-lcudart" flag to the Makefile.

The problem is that when I compile my main project, I get this error:

```
expected primary-expression before ',' token
```

and is referring to the line in **extern.cc** where I call the "gpucaller" function.

Does anyone know how to get this right?

EDIT: I've tried compiling again, this time removing the arguments from the *gpucaller*'s function definition (and obviously not passing any arguments to the function, which is wrong because I *need* to pass arguments). It compiled just fine.

So the problem is that *gpucaller*'s argument types aren't recognized, I have no idea why (I've included the headers where the arguments' types are declared, ie "qc/operator.h" and "qc/quStates.h"). Does anyone have a solution to this?

My project's Makefile is this:

```
VERSION=0.6.3

# Directory for Standard .qcl files

QCLDIR = /usr/local/lib/qcl

# Path for qcl binaries

QCLBIN = /usr/local/bin

ARCH = `g++ -dumpmachine || echo bin`

# Comment out if you want to compile for a different target architecture
# To build libqc.a, you will also have to edit qc/Makefile!

#ARCH = i686-linux
#ARCHOPT = -m32 -march=i686

# Debugging and optimization options

#DEBUG = -g -pg -DQCL_DEBUG -DQC_DEBUG
#DEBUG = -g -DQCL_DEBUG -DQC_DEBUG
DEBUG = -O2 -g -DQCL_DEBUG -DQC_DEBUG
#DEBUG = -O2

# Plotting support 
#
# Comment out if you don't have GNU libplotter and X

PLOPT = -DQCL_PLOT
PLLIB = -L/usr/X11/lib -lplotter

# Readline support
#
# Comment out if you don't have GNU readline on your system
# explicit linking against libtermcap or libncurses may be required

RLOPT = -DQCL_USE_READLINE
#RLLIB = -lreadline
RLLIB = -lreadline -lncurses

# Interrupt support
#
# Comment out if your system doesn't support ANSI C signal handling

IRQOPT = -DQCL_IRQ

# Replace with lex and yacc on non-GNU systems (untested)

LEX = flex
YACC = bison 
INSTALL = install

##### You shouldn't have to edit the stuff below #####

DATE = `date +"%y.%m.%d-%H%M"`

QCDIR = qc
QCLIB = $(QCDIR)/libqc.a
QCLINC = lib

#CXX = g++
#CPP = $(CC) -E
CXXFLAGS = -c $(ARCHOPT) -Wall $(DEBUG) $(PLOPT) $(RLOPT) $(IRQOPT) -I$(QCDIR) -DDEF_INCLUDE_PATH="\"$(QCLDIR)\""
LDFLAGS = $(ARCHOPT) -L$(QCDIR) $(DEBUG) $(PLLIB) -lm -lfl -lqc $(RLLIB) -L"/usr/local/cuda/lib" -lcudart

FILESCC = $(wildcard *.cc)
FILESH = $(wildcard *.h)

SOURCE = $(FILESCC) $(FILESH) qcl.lex qcl.y Makefile

OBJECTS = types.o syntax.o typcheck.o symbols.o error.o \
          lex.o yacc.o print.o quheap.o extern.o eval.o exec.o \
          parse.o options.o debug.o cond.o dump.o plot.o format.o cuda_kernel.o

all: do-it-all

ifeq (.depend,$(wildcard .depend))
include .depend
do-it-all: build
else
do-it-all: dep
    $(MAKE)
endif

#### Rules for depend

dep: lex.cc yacc.cc yacc.h $(QCLIB)
    for i in *.cc; do \
      $(CPP) -I$(QCDIR) -MM $$i; \
    done > .depend

lex.cc: qcl.lex yacc.h
    $(LEX) -olex.cc qcl.lex

yacc.cc: qcl.y
    $(YACC) -t -d -o yacc.cc qcl.y

yacc.h: yacc.cc
    mv yacc.*?h yacc.h

$(QCLIB):
    cd $(QCDIR) && $(MAKE) libqc.a

#### Rules for build

build: qcl $(QCLINC)/default.qcl

qcl: $(OBJECTS) qcl.o $(QCLIB)
    $(CXX) $(OBJECTS) qcl.o $(LDFLAGS) -o qcl

$(QCLINC)/default.qcl: extern.cc
    grep "^//!" extern.cc | cut -c5- > $(QCLINC)/default.qcl

checkinst:
    [ -f ./qcl -a -f $(QCLINC)/default.qcl ] || $(MAKE) build

install: checkinst
    $(INSTALL) -m 0755 -d $(QCLBIN) $(QCLDIR)
    $(INSTALL) -m 0755 ./qcl $(QCLBIN)
    $(INSTALL) -m 0644 ./$(QCLINC)/*.qcl $(QCLDIR)

uninstall:
    -rm -f $(QCLBIN)/qcl
    -rm -f $(QCLDIR)/*.qcl
    -rmdir $(QCLDIR)

#### Other Functions

edit:
    nedit $(SOURCE) &

clean:
    rm -f *.o lex.* yacc.* 
    cd $(QCDIR) && $(MAKE) clean

clear: clean
    rm -f qcl $(QCLINC)/default.qcl .depend
    cd $(QCDIR) && $(MAKE) clear

dist-src: dep
    mkdir qcl-$(VERSION)
    cp README CHANGES COPYING .depend $(SOURCE) qcl-$(VERSION) 
    mkdir qcl-$(VERSION)/qc
    cp qc/Makefile qc/*.h qc/*.cc qcl-$(VERSION)/qc
    cp -r lib qcl-$(VERSION)
    tar czf qcl-$(VERSION).tgz --owner=0 --group=0 qcl-$(VERSION)
    rm -r qcl-$(VERSION)

dist-bin: build
    mkdir qcl-$(VERSION)-$(ARCH)
    cp Makefile README CHANGES COPYING qcl qcl-$(VERSION)-$(ARCH) 
    cp -r lib qcl-$(VERSION)-$(ARCH)
    tar czf qcl-$(VERSION)-$(ARCH).tgz --owner=0 --group=0 qcl-$(VERSION)-$(ARCH)
    rm -r qcl-$(VERSION)-$(ARCH)

upload: dist-src
    scp qcl-$(VERSION)*.tgz oemer@tph.tuwien.ac.at:html/tgz

scp: dist-src
    scp qcl-$(VERSION).tgz oemer@tph.tuwien.ac.at:bak/qcl-$(DATE).tgz
```

The only changes that I've added to the original Makefile is adding "cuda_kernel.o" to the OBJECTS' line, and adding the "-lcudart" flag to LDFLAGS.

UPDATE: Thanks **harrism** for helping me out. I was passing a type as a parameter.

Comment: I think you need to add more information.  Can you include a more complete example of the code making the call, including the actual types?  I think as lurscher says the error is that the compiler does not see the declaration of type1 (missing include file?).

Comment: Don't know it it has something to do with this but don't name your header file cuda.h. That is one of the actual include files of CUDA. Maybe this can cause problems.

Comment: I've renamed my header, but I still get that error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
gpucaller(opBit, q);
```

You are passing a type name (`opBit`) as a function parameter, which is not valid C or C++.  It looks like you need to do this instead:

```
gpucaller(op, q);
```

Comment: Thanks, I wasted 2 days because of this, I need to be more carefull.

Answer (score 0):

Does it literally look like this in `cuda.h`?

```
void gpucaller(type1 param1, type2 param2);
```

Are `type1` and `type2` declared anywhere so that your regular C++ compiler know what these types are? If not, then you'd get an error like you're saying you're getting.

Comment: No, they have different type and they compile just fine (I've included the headers with their definitions), I just wanted to make a simple presentation of what I'm dealing with.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem code is pretty big and complex at the moment. Try to strip it down to a more simple failure case and update your question once you have that. It'll make it easier to attempt reproduction. Strip out the cuda timer code, the `switch case`, replace implementation details with  `...` where it doesn't matter, etc.

I compile with msvc and nvcc then link with icl; so if you can make a simple example I can see if it compiles with a totally different compiler setup. That should narrow down the problem.

---

Even though renaming your own header `cuda.h` to `somethingspecific.h` didn't help, I don't think it's a good idea to leave it as `cuda.h`. It's confusing and a potential source of problems.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I've posted a new question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6391628/compiler-error-while-linking-cuda-code-to-cpp-file